# Significado de IController devuelto en operador ternario

Tags: c#

¿Alguien me podria decir qué me esta queriendo decir esta sentencia?

```
                 return controllerType != null
                         ? _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController
                           : base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
```

Dentro del código:

```
using Dominio.MesaEntrada.Expedientes;

namespace MVC.Client.Extensiones.ControllerFactories
{
    public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

        public UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }


        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            try
            {
                 return controllerType != null
                         ? _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController
                           : base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                //Log the exception if needed
                //Try to resolve using default factory
                return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega el código en la pregunta. No es agregar una imagen. gracias

Comment: ok gracias ya lo agregare soy nuevo en este foro

Comment: ¿A cuál sentencia te refieres?

Comment: Vendria a ser la parte del Try{

Answer (score 0):

Te dice que si `controllerType != null` entonces devuelve

```
_container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController
```

por contra, si `controllerType == null` devuelve

```
base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType)
```

Es un operador ternario, mas explicado en:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Gracias man, mira te comento soy nuevo en esto de la programacion en c# .net entre en una pasantia de mi facu en un lugar y bueno me asignaron la tarea de crear una solapa que muestre los datos de un expediente, en un portal que ellos tienen y bueno conoces algun buen sitio donde tengan buenos tutoriales

Comment: buenas, te recomiendo dos libros: +6.0+in+a+Nutshell y Apress.C.7th.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad es un `if` pero de una línea, ejemplo:

**`If` tradicional:**

```
 string resultado = "";    
 if (bandera){
    resultado = "Bandera es verdadero.";
 }else{
    resultado = "Bandera es falso.";
 }
```

**`If` simplificado:**

```
 string resultado = bandera ? "Bandera es verdadero." : "Bandera es falso.";
```

Los dos ejemplos anteriores hacen lo mismos, agregarle valor a la variable resultado en base a si la variable bandera es `true` o `false`.

Explicado de otra forma el `if` simplificado se divide en tres secciones:

1. Condición
2. Resultado verdadero
3. Resultado falso

La sintaxis seria la siguiente:

```
<condicion> ? <resultado true> : <resultado false>
```

Espero haberte podido ayudar, saludos.

**Explicación del código:**

```
 protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            try
            {
                 return controllerType != null
                         ? _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController
                           : base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                //Log the exception if needed
                //Try to resolve using default factory
                return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            }
         }
```

El método `GetControllerInstance` recibe un objeto `System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext` y aparte recibe que tipo de objeto es: `Type controllerType`, que puede tener datos o ser `null`

lo que hace primero es preguntar si el tipo recibido no es `null`:

```
controllerType != null
```

Si se cumple esta condición:

```
_container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController
```

`_container` <--- es un objeto que tienes definido mas arriba

Al parecer llama la método `.Resolve` que recibe como parametor el `controllerType` y lo convierte al tipo `IController` <-- Para que te retorne el `controller` que se requiere para ese tipo de `controller`

Si no se cumple la condición o si el tipo de `controller` es `null`:

```
base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType)
```

Te esta regresando una instancia de la base (`DefaultControllerFactory`), y se esta basando en el `controllerType` recibido y en `requestContext`

En pocas palabras este código esta haciendo uso de Interfaces y herencia para obtener un objeto de tipo `IController` (debe ser una interface), con el `IF` lo único que hace es validar para que no te regrese un objeto `null` o vació.

Comment: Como seria aplicado al codigo que mostre

Comment: En pocas palabras este código esta haciendo uso de Interfaces y herencia para obtener un objeto de tipo IController (debe ser una interface), con el IF lo único que hace es validar para que no te regrese un objeto null o vació.

Es código muy genérico con nivel de abstracción medio-alto, al parecer para que se pueda reutilizar sin importar los tipos de objetos que estés manejando.  No sé si corresponde algún patrón de diseño, seguramente sí, pero los desconozco.